# How to put logo in Navbar without png square

Tags: html, css, image, navbar, photoshop

**Using template engine as PUG**

*Html body*

```
    nav#navbar
        ul.flex-container
          div#logo
              img(src='/static/logo3.png')
```

[image]
*This is what image logo3.png looks*

[image]

**Can you suggest any css property?
Or photoshop tool to do it.
Searched but found opacity property which doesn't help.**

Comment: Looks to me like, you'll have to edit the png to really have an empty/clear background.

Comment: I edited png background by refining edges which consumes alot of time.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Kdhere would appreciate if you accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Google` for more of these simplest tasks. This is not the right place to ask these type of questions. You can use an online background remover like https://remove.bg to remove backgrounds if you are not familiar with image editing apps. Btw, here's your updated image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vivek for your valueable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

1. We can use background remover online tool as Vivek mention.
2. We can also do it by using css *Invert which changes white background to black. We can also use contrast and other property for it *[Css filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert)

> ```
> #logo img{
>     filter: invert(1);
>     height: 50px;
>      width: 60px;
> }
> ```

**This is result of invert function**
[image]

Thanks everyone who helped me in this!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this image is not transparent, you can see the gray and white chessboard pattern in the background.

I suggest you should use a photo editing app to select the content and delete everything other than the selection.

Comment: How to get transparent image when I download transparent logo image (chess box still appears). Do we have any other format for it? Except png which can do it.

Comment: Thats is how you see a png my guy

Comment: Most sites and apps add that pattern to the preview but the original file itself does not have that.  Also Vivek's answer is the solution for you, as you can see that image does not have any chessboard pattern. @Kdhere